# Regular Expression with specific criteria

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hey everyone, I'm trying to type a regular expression that follows the following format:

`someone@somewhere.com` or `some.one@some.where.com`

There are no special characters or numbers permitted for this criteria. I thought I had it down, but I'm a bit rusty with regular expressions and when I tested mine, it failed all across the boards. So far, my regular is expression is:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+/.?[a-zA-Z]*@[a-zA-Z]+/.?[a-zA-Z]*/.com$
```

If anyone could help me, it would greatly be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex looks good. I think you need to change the / to \ in front of the . .
Additionally, if you don't want someone.@somewhere..com pass your regex, u should change your regex to

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?@[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?\.com$
```

(not completely sure about the brackets () though, but i think that should be working)

Comment: That `(\.[a-zA-Z])` (in both places) should be `(\.[a-zA-Z]+)`.  Then you won't need to follow it with `[a-zA-Z]*`.

Answer (score 1):

its a backslash to espace dots. Also put the the parenthesis around the . and what follows otherwise an email like abc.@cde..com would be valid.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?@[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?\.com$
```

Comment: sorry, but did you copy & paste your answer from our answers?

Comment: haha, I did not even know there were answers when I typed mine :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks mostly OK.  Change your `/` to `\` though...

For the second case, I would ensure that if you have a `.` in the middle, it must be followed by more letters:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?@[a-zA-Z]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)?\.com$
```